# How to get name of file that's being opened in load_pre callback

Tags: scripting

I have script that looks like this:

```
@persistent
def PreLoad_Handler(foo):
    openedSceneFile = bpy.data.filepath
    
    print(f"openedSceneFile: {openedSceneFile}")
    p4Result = p4.GetP4FileStats(openedSceneFile)
    if p4Result[0]:
        print("File need update")
    else:
        print("File up to date")

def register():
    bpy.app.handlers.load_pre.append(PreLoad_Handler)
```

My problem is that openedSceneFile contains path to file that already opened. Not the one that's being opened and that triggered the callback.

Is there a way how to access the correct file name?

I don't want to use load_post callback. That's too late. I'd have to close the file, update it and open again which makes no sense to me.

Comment: "Scene" and "file" are two different things. A .blend file can contain multiple scenes, but it seems you are talking just about the file, not about any scenes in the file.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I'm talking about .blend file.

Comment: I think your reasoning fails when you assume that at the time `load_pre` is fired, blender knows *which* file is going to be opened. I think `load_pre` only knows that the *current* file is going to close, so it doesn't give you any meaningful information about what the next one will be. Maybe it's a XY problem, and the question you should ask is do you really need to run your script before `load_post` fires ?

Comment: Yea. I realized that @Gorgious. And I did asked the question. My goal is to make sure artist in multi-user environment will always work with up to date file. One way I'm used to do that for other 3D applications is that before loading of a file I check if it's up to date . And if it's not I give user option to update it before the file is even loaded. It's simple and clean solution.
Now I'll have to really open the file, give user the same option and if he  want's to update it then close the file, update and open again. That's wasting of time if you ask me... So my answer is yes. I do need it

Comment: Also I'd add that when load_pre is triggered Blender itself definitely knows what file is being opened. That's by definition, because the callback is called when I actually select file in open dialog and hit Open button and there is no additional file selection after that
It's just it not being passed into python that's a problem.

Answer (score 0):

This information does not exist before `bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile()` operator is run and the operator loads the file. It seems it is not possible to access this information from `load_pre` handler.

You could replace bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile() operator itself, but you need a way to load the file, and there is no other way to do that from Python API except to use that operator, so you cannot just redefine it and it has to remain functional. You would need to make a new operator for opening files and replace the original one in the File menu(and also deal with any hotkeys associated with open_mainfile() operator) so you would need to rewrite the whole file menu. It's in `C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.5\3.5\scripts\startup\bl_ui\space_topbar.py` so you can copy the code and re-register it. Something like that:

```
import bpy

from bpy.app.translations import (
    pgettext_iface as iface_,
    contexts as i18n_contexts,
)

class My_File_Menu(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_label = "File"
    bl_idname = "TOPBAR_MT_file"
    
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        layout.operator_context = 'INVOKE_AREA'
        layout.menu("TOPBAR_MT_file_new", text="New", text_ctxt=i18n_contexts.id_windowmanager, icon='FILE_NEW')
        layout.operator("wm.open_mainfile", text="Open...", icon='FILE_FOLDER')
# ... 


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(My_File_Menu)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(My_File_Menu)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

You can run any code before loading the file in your custom operator. Text Editor's Templates -> Python menu has examples how to make operators. "Operator File Import" is probably the most relevant.

Comment: Thanks Martynas. However that's not really the answer I was looking for :-) 
Rewriting the File menu may not even be the proper option. There are other ways how to open .blend file. Drag&Drop, command line, script... It seems crazy to me to handle all that just because I want to know name of the file that Blender is opening. 

Maybe my question is not really valid, but here I even wonder what's the usage of load_pre callback if it will not tell what's being loaded. 

Maybe there is another way how to get such information?

Comment: I think it may be possible to change drag and drop operator as well.This is not really the answer I wanted to give as well. But as far as I know that's how it is. Maybe someone knows something I don't.

Comment: There is [Message Bus](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.msgbus.html) I am not very familiar with how it works, but I think it works when datablocks are updated, so if the file is not loaded yet, there is nothing that changed. Blender's Python API is amassing, but it doesn't allays have everything.

Comment: I think it's really not possible to get that information from the handler. That seems to be the answer to your question unfortunately. Maybe try asking the developers on  https://devtalk.blender.org/